# Test controllers in gem with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, rubygems

I wonder how to test controllers outside of rails - in a new gem.

How to mock them and how to use Rails controller test helpers like `get` and `post`?

I am trying to test `before_filter` that is executed from developed module.

Comment: This might be helpful http://codingdaily.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/test-a-gem-with-the-rails-3-stack/